# Need alternative POST method for window.open, showmodeldialog and startDownload

Tags: javascript

In Javascript currently these functions are sending GET request window.open, showmodeldialog and startDownload.
What is the alternative method to send these request as POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="..." target="myWindow">
   <!-- Whatever you need -->
</form>
```

And in your javascript:

```
<script>
  window.open("about:blank", "myWindow", /*additional params...*/);
  document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I am not using FORM, In window.open(url) I am sending an URL to another page,But It send the request as GET and not secured, IS there any methods to send URL as POST. At the same time I need a replacement methods for showmodeldialog and startDownload in Java script.

Comment: And there is no way you can build a <form> element with hidden inputs in your code as to simulate this POST call?  I think it's the easiest way (unless you can imagine something using prototype or jQuery libraries doing something similar)

Comment: Ok thats fine, Do you know any alternative POST methods for showmodeldialog and startDownload?